# return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('ID') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'") , 0) == 1) ? true : false;

Tags: php, sql

```
function user_exists($username)
{
    $username = sanitize($username);
    //query = ;
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('ID') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'") , 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

This code gives the error:

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\James\Desktop\Container\XAMPP\htdocs\Triiline1\login.php on line 23
```

I've looked around and the other questions fixing this don't seem to fix my problem.

I am also confused as to the end of the line: `? true : false;`
I got that code from a phpacademy tutorial on youtube, and I can't find documentation on it anywhere. I suspect it may be outdated?

Comment: You have your answer below to the error.  Read up on ternary operation in PHP for the answer about the `? true : false` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, identifier quote character is the backtick " ` " (not single quote) as stated here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html.  Please update your query to use back ticks on table name and column names as follows:

```
"SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"
```

Because the query did not succeed, your `mysql_query` returned `false` which is the reason for that error.  Please have a look at the documentation for `mysql_query` here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and check the "Return Values" section thoroughly.

Also as you mention `tutorial` then I believe you are beginning to learn PHP with DB development, in which case its better to start learning either `mysqli` http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or `PDO` http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php as `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: This is good answer. I would add to this that there is no virtue in cramming as much code as possible into one line. No one is going to say "Neat! look how much code he fit into that one line".  You should break that code up into multiple lines and add proper error handling (handling all possible responses to the query attempt for example). It will make debugging 1000x easier. If you had error handling here, and dumped out the `mysql_error()` result, you wouldn't have even needed to ask this question as the error message would have indicated your syntax problem.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBrant for the guide, will absolutely keep these kinds of suggestions in mind.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I've been doing that backtick part wrong this entire time. By MySQL is deprecated, do you mean that all of this software I've downloaded is outdated? I have MySQL 5.5.32, is MySQLi a different new program or an update on commands?

And Mike Brant, I originally had the line split, but I put it all together to see if that would fix the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: *I think I have PHP 5.5.32, I misread that. The question still stands though.